# Can we implement something that resembles the MathJax that Math.SE has?

Tags: discussion

This seems easy to do since it is already in place on another site on the network, and useful because some questions (especially logic-related) can be written/answered more clearly with LaTeX.

Comment: This has been addressed before so I'm closing as duplicate for simplicity/organizational purposes. See [LateX/WebteX availability?](http://meta.philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/43/latex-webtex-availability) Also, it probably wouldn't be added to a BETA site on principle (although from what I see of the site stats we are pretty close to meeting 'Excellent' on all Graduation requirements). Also, this comment suggestion seems like a good idea in the meantime: http://www.texpaste.com/

Comment: We would use this mainly for logics, right? Note that HTML has &..; codes for logics that you can use, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logic_symbols. This doesn't work in comments, but does in questions.